# How can I see if a user deleted a folder in a shared resource using AD?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, shared-folders

Is there any way to see if a user deleted a folder in a shared resource (we have Active Directory)?

I need to see if someone is removing folders or if they do actually "magically disappear".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you should be able to audit the delete events.

In Group Policy audit for Object Access - Success.

Then at the folder you want to trigger the events, set the Audit for successful deletion of files and folders.  [Here](http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2008/03/use-auditing-to-track-who-deleted-your-files/) is a website that talks about that.

When a file/folder is deleted, an event log entry will be made.  You may have to search through the event log entries to find the specific file/folder of interest.

Answer (score 1):

There's an "inspection" tab in the advanced security properties, though you need to configure group policy in addition to this.

Comment: How to set up this group policy?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea :(